# Re using same tabs in different tabviews

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a tab which contains multiple datatables. On the basis of some criteria I need to dynamically design same tab(with same content) in different tabview.How can I reuse this.Since the mapping is same,if I enter some data on one tab it would get reflect on the other tabs as well.
Please suggest..!!

Comment: @Kukeltje could you please explain this in detail.I didn't understand what you're trying to say :)

Comment: can i include the same xhtml file in other tab or do I need to create another xhtml file

Comment: Don't be rude mate...i only asked this because i'm facing some issues with duplicate id in case of using same xhtml file on different tabs. If you don't want to answer then don't waste your time and energy over this post.....Thanks :)

Comment: TRY... (not rude, just explicit)

Comment: JSF has a thing called `Composite Components`. Maybe that can help you?